# React Native with reCATPCHA

Tags: javascript, react-native, cross-domain, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement the [google reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/) in my react native app. I'm using a wrapped webview.

```
<WebView 
    javaScriptEnabled={true} 
    mixedContentMode={'always'} 
    style={{height: 200}} 
    source={{
        html: this.getWebviewContent()
    }}/>


getWebviewContent(){
    var originalForm = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script></head><body><form action="[POST_URL]" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="[TITLE]"><input type="hidden" value="[DESCRIPTION]"><input type="hidden" value="[URL]"><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<My key>"></div><input type="submit" value="Send"/></form></body></html>'
    var tmp =  originalForm
        .replace("[POST_URL]", "http://localhost:3000/v1/video")
        .replace("[TITLE]", this.state.form.title)
        .replace("[DESCRIPTION]", this.state.form.description)
        .replace("[URL]", this.state.form.url); 

    return tmp; 
}
```

If I render it, it gives me the following error: 
[image: ERROR for site owner: Invalid domain for site key]

I have a theory that it doesn't want to cooperate since I'm running it as a "file" in the `WebView` and that you cannot add files as part of the domain in the Google dashboard.

Is there any way of either added `file://` permissions in the reCAPTCHA dashboard of Google or any way of faking a domain, so that I can add that faked domain in the dashboard. Or am I completely lost and the issue is something else?

Comment: Does it work if you set a domain with baseUrl? `<WebView source={{ html: this.getWebviewContent(), baseUrl: 'http://your-domain.com' }}`

Comment: Yes, that does work! Thanks a lot for your feedback. If you write a example solution I can set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a domain for your WebView by setting `baseUrl` in [`source`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#source) prop:

```
<WebView 
    javaScriptEnabled={true} 
    mixedContentMode={'always'} 
    style={{height: 200}} 
    source={{
        html: this.getWebviewContent(),
        baseUrl: 'http://your-domain.com' // <-- SET YOUR DOMAIN HERE
    }}/>


getWebviewContent(){
    var originalForm = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script></head><body><form action="[POST_URL]" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="[TITLE]"><input type="hidden" value="[DESCRIPTION]"><input type="hidden" value="[URL]"><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<My key>"></div><input type="submit" value="Send"/></form></body></html>'
    var tmp =  originalForm
        .replace("[POST_URL]", "http://localhost:3000/v1/video")
        .replace("[TITLE]", this.state.form.title)
        .replace("[DESCRIPTION]", this.state.form.description)
        .replace("[URL]", this.state.form.url); 

    return tmp; 
}
```

Comment: where one have to specify sitekey? what is baseUrl for RN app?