# how to use reCaptcha in ReactNative app?

Tags: react-native, recaptcha

I have found following lib for use reCaptcha in RN app

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-recaptcha

my code is

```
  import ReCaptcha from 'react-native-recaptcha';
  ...
  <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
    <ReCaptcha
      sitekey={'test'}
    />
  </View>
```

but no recaptcha is displayed. 
Also I have tried sitekey used in one of my websites where reCaptcha worked properly - still nothing.
Do I miss something?

p.s. github of this lib not exists (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no lib exist for **reCaptcha** in react native. So you need to use **wrapped webview** for it, I know it is slow and may include your requirment, but I think it is only solution.

Please see  [React Native with reCATPCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994203/react-native-with-recatpcha) and https://github.com/evenchange4/react-grecaptcha

Comment: react-grecaptcha is React, not RN component, is this possible to use React component in RN?

Comment: please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123840/can-i-use-reactjs-library-in-react-native

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a component that does something similar to what Priya suggested. It caters specifically to react-native and uses google recaptcha v3. Feel free to check it out and make a PR if you would like to customize it or feel that something could be done better :)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-recaptcha-v3

Answer (score 2):

[react-native-recaptcha-that-works](https://github.com/douglasjunior/react-native-recaptcha-that-works) worked for me - has also the invisible option for better UX.