# TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _auth.RecaptchaVerifier')

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I am trying to add firebase auth to my mobile application using this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#web-version-9_1) to support phone number authentication.

A minimal version of my code is

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput
} from "react-native";
import Firebase from '../config/firebase';
import { getAuth, signInWithPhoneNumber, RecaptchaVerifier } from "firebase/auth";

const WelcomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  function continueButton() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.9}
        onPress={async () =>   {  
          console.log("Inside on press");
          window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
            'size': 'invisible',
            'callback': (response) => {
              // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
            }
          }, auth);
          navigation.navigate("Verification", {confirm: confirmation})}}
      >
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on the continue button, the `continueButton()` function is triggered, which results in the given error

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _auth.RecaptchaVerifier')]
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:691:17 in _performTransitionSideEffects
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:628:6 in _receiveSignal
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:524:8 in responderEventHandlers.onResponderRelease
```

I have been trying to figure out the root cause of the issue but could not figure out anything. Can you please help me fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
const WelcomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  function continueButton() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.9}
        onPress={async () =>   {  
          console.log("Inside on press");
          window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
            'size': 'invisible',
            'callback': (response) => {
              return response; // or return some required value here.
            }
          }, auth);
          navigation.navigate("Verification", {confirm: confirmation})}}
      >
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Tried the suggested code, still its giving me the same error.

Comment: Sorry, in that you need to revisit the source from where you got the code  and check for missing info, or you can share that link here.

Comment: I got the code from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#web-version-9_1. Can you please have a quick look to see if you can find any issue in my approach

Comment: Yes  ok, let me check

Comment: I'm not much familiar with react-native but you can implement in this way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069531/how-to-use-recaptcha-in-reactnative-app

Comment: Instead of following direct docs, please find some implemented code. You will get better bug fixing there.